# Firebase querying efficiency using where field vs alternative

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have got a firebase app which involves a collection containing posts that have been made on the app each with a document containing the data for the post. As a user, you are able to like a post and the UID's of your liked posts are stored in the user document. As past of the app I want to be able to retrieve all posts that have been liked by a user. I have got two ways of doing this:

**First Option** I could user the where field option:

```
    static func getLikedPosts(likedIDs: [String], completion: @escaping ((_ data: [Post]) -> Void))  {
        db.collection("posts").whereField("postID", in: likedIDs).getDocuments {(querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print(err)
            } else {
                var listings: [Listing] = []

                for doc in querySnapshot!.documents {
                   
                    // ...
                    let post = Post()
                    posts.append(post)
                }

                completion(posts)
            }
        }
    }
```

**Second Option** is that I've got a function to get a single post:

```
    static func getPost(listingID: String, completion: @escaping ((_ data: Post) -> Void)) {
        db.collection("posts").document(postID).getDocument { (doc, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print(err)
            } else {
                if let doc = doc, doc.exists {
                    
                    
                    if let data = doc.data() {
                        
                        // ...
                        let post = Post()
                        completion(post)
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and then to get all the liked posts I use the following function:

```
    static func getLikedPosts(likedIDs: [String], completion: @escaping ((_ data: [Post]) -> Void)) {
        var posts = [Post]()
        for id in likedIDs {
            getPost(postID: id) { (post) in

                listings.append(post)
                
                if posts.count == likedIDs.count {
                    completion(posts)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My question is which of these two options if more efficient/scalable on a large number of posts, or if there is a better option? I would imagine using the where field would be higher time complexity but unsure on how firebase manages these queries.

Answer (score 1):

There is going to be no significant performance difference between these two approaches. I personally prefer getting each post by its ID, as it means I don't hv to deal with the limit of 10 values for an `in` query. But as said: that is a personal preference only.

The only better option would be if you can get the favorites for a user with a equality query (`==`) or a range query (`>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=`), but I don't seen option for that for this use-case.

The other alternative is to store a user's favorited posts in a separate (sub)collection for that user, so that you can then simply read that entire collection. This means you'll be duplicating the posts when they are written, and keeping it up to data when they are updated, but in exchange you'll get faster, and more scalable read behavior.

This is a common trade-off when using NoSQL databases: and is an implementation of the classic space vs time trade-off.